# Recursively read through a folder tree and determine which folders have files

Tags: python, python-2.7, directory

I've written a program to look through images inside a folder and extract the embedded EXIF data. Currently I'm using the code below to get paths for all the files inside a folder, the variable 'folder_name' is input by the user. The list created is then used by the program to cycle through all the images.

```
file_names = glob(join(expanduser('~'),'Desktop',folder_name,'*'))
```

Now I want to add a bit of functionality, that is the ability to look through a folder tree and return only the folders with images/files in them. This list could then be passed into the bit of code above to do the rest. I just need a pointer as to where to look to develop this.

Also how could I select and output just the image files, using `endswith(.jpg)` on the file path didn't work due to case sensitivity.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. I think your question is too broad for this site. Basically, you are asking the users here to design your algorithm for you.

Comment: I guess for recursive walking trought dir tree will be good **os.walk**, 
For case sensitivnes just use to_lower function at file name and comparewith lowecase extension

Comment: Edited my question Konstantin. Thanks Take Care will look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) + [mimetypes.guess_type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mimetypes.html#mimetypes.guess_type) like so

```
import os
import os.path
import mimetypes
top="."
imagefiles=[]
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top):
    for fn in files:
        t,e= mimetypes.guess_type(fn, strict=False)
        if t.startswith("image/"):
            imagefiles.append(os.path.join(root,fn)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work around case-sensitivity by applying the `.lower()` string method to both strings before comparing them.